# Is it possible to get a Bloomberg keyboard to work on a standard PC?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have just gotten my hands on a [Bloomberg Keyboard](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/blog/look-back-bloomberg-keyboard/) (Model CTB100; aka: The 2004 “Centerboard” model) and it looks quite interesting.

[image: Bloomberg Keyboard: Model CTB100]

It’s got a shed load of extra buttons (hopefully programmable), a USB port on the back, place for microphone, headphones, phone jack (God only knows why!) and a small LCD display.

There is a single cable coming out the back of this, and it has a USB port, PS2 connection, a port which reminds me of the old Commodore 64 power connection (female) and two 3.5mm audio cables (microphone and audio I am guessing).

The port which reminds me of the C64 power is probably a power port of some sorts. Plugging it into a standard Windows laptop does nothing. I don’t have the power lead, but hope to find one soon.

Anyway, there is very little information about these on-line, and I am wondering can they be reprogrammed to work as a standard keyboard? I am a developer, so using extra keys for hot keys in Visual Studio or some other app would be very handy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the drivers from http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/software_support/ ?

Comment: downloaded it and tried installing it, but it wants an "open bloomberg edition"... which i dont have...

Comment: Pictures! Also, try crossposting to keyboard enthusiast sites - i like [geekhack](http://geekhack.org/index.php) but there's others